# How to properly cancel a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, cancellation

I've got a GUI form which is acting as the main thread, while I've got a different class for the actual work which is needed to be done.

Is there a way to properly check the `CancellationPending` property of the worker since it's being activated from a different class, other than passing the worker as a parameter for the "DoJob" method so it could check the property?

The code (in the main class):

```
// This method is registered as the DoWork method for the worker
private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    workClassInstance.DoJob();
}

private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
    {
        bw.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really; you pretty much need to check the `IsCancelled` property of the BGW periodically to properly cancel.  If it's important that a given operation explicitly *not* know about the BGW then there are a few options.

---

One thing you can do if it's really important to not expose the BGW is to use a `CancellationToken` instead.  You can create a `CancellationTokenSource` and expose it to whatever is responsible for canceling the task, and then pass the `Token` value of the cts to whatever is responsible for being canceled.

---

Another option is that you could pass a `Func<bool>` as a parameter to `DoJob`.  That function, when invoked, would return whether or not the task has currently requested cancellation.  You would then call it like so:

```
workClassInstance.DoJob(()=> worker.CancellationPending);
```

You've now "hidden" the background worker from the `workClassInstance` and only exposed that aspect of its functionality that it needs, namely whether or not cancellation has been requested.